# Determine if two lines are parallel and distinct.

Tags: calculus

Ok, so I have a vector equation: $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle 2,0,9\rangle + t\langle -1,5,2\rangle$ and another line $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle 3,-5, 10\rangle + t\langle 1,-5,-2\rangle$. How do I know whether the two lines are parallel distinct?

What I did:

$n_1 = \langle -1,5,2\rangle$;
$n_2 = -\langle -1,5,2\rangle$

Since the direction vectors are the same, they are parallel.

But how do I know they are distinct? My teacher tried to explain this to me, but didn't do a very good job.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the direction vectors are scalar multiples, the lines will be parallel. To show they are distinct, you need to show, for example, that $(3,-5,10)$ is *not* on the first line. You'd need $3=2-t$, so $t=-1$. Do the other coordinates match up?